# What resources exist for Database performance-tuning?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle, postgresql

What good resources exist for understanding database tuning on the major engines and advancing your knowledge in that area?

The idea of this question is to collect the shed load of resources that invariably exist, so that people can have a "one stop" knowledge shop of the good, peer approved resources.

---

**General SQL**

- [Book: SQL Performance Tuning](http://books.google.com/books?id=3H9CC54qYeEC&dq=sql+performance+tuning&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=1dDoSYmjMOrlnQfX-bSYBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4)
- [Book: SQL Tuning](http://books.google.com/books?id=pKXF7UU0gBYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=sql%2Btuning)
- [Book: The Art of SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008945)
- [Book: Refactoring SQL Applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=gjyd3IOrwz4C&lpg=PP1&dq=refactoring%20sql%20applications&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [Book: Database tuning: principles, experiments, and troubleshooting techniques](http://books.google.com/books?id=1CJdgVO8PwAC&lpg=PR21&dq=database%20tuning%20principles&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [Use The Index, Luke! - A Guide to database performance for developers](http://Use-The-Index-Luke.com/)

**PostgreSQL** ([wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/)) ([PGsearch](http://www.pgsql.ru/db/pgsearch/))

- [Performance Optimization](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization)
- [Quick PostgreSQL Optimization](http://www.mohawksoft.org/?q=node/56)
- [Explain Analyze Interpreter](http://explain.depesz.com/)
- [PostgreSQL Performance Tips](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/performance-tips.html)
- [Book: PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance](https://www.packtpub.com/postgresql-90-high-performance/book)

**MySQL**

- [Hidden Features of MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368858/hidden-features-of-mysql)
- [Book: High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718/) / [Blog: High Performance MySQL](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/)
- [Blog: Xaprb (for MySQL DBAs)](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/)

**Oracle**

- [How to ask Oracle tuning questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325)
- [How do you interpret a query's explain plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79266/how-do-you-interpret-a-querys-explain-plan)
- [Oracle Advanced Tuning Scripts](http://www.ixora.com.au/scripts/)
- [Oracle Database Performance Tuning Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/toc.htm)
- [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com)
- [Oracle Database SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm)
- [Book: Understanding Oracle Performance](http://www.amazon.ca/Troubleshooting-Oracle-Performance-Christian-Antognini/dp/1590599179)
- [Book: Optimizing Oracle Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600527X)
- [Book: Troubleshooting Oracle Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599179)
- [Book: Cost-Based Oracle Fundamentals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596366)

**MS SQL Server**

- [SQL Server Performance](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/index.aspx)
- [eBook: High Performance SQL Server](http://downloads.red-gate.com/ebooks/HighPerformanceSQL_ebook.zip)
- [SO Question: What are the best SQL Server performance optimization techniques?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103423/what-are-the-best-sql-server-performance-optimization-techniques)
- [Brent Ozar's Perf Tuning Page](http://www.brentozar.com/sql-server-performance-tuning/)
- [SqlServerPedia's Perf Tuning Page](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9805.performance-tuning.aspx)
- [Book: Sql Server 2008 Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626243)
- [How to Identify Slow Running Queries with SQL Profiler](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/)

**Sybase SQL Anywhere**

- [Blog: SQL Anywhere](http://sqlanywhere.blogspot.com/)
- [Book: SQL Anywhere Studio 9  Developer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556225067)

**JDBC**

- [JDBC Performance Tips](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/jdbc.shtml)

Comment: MySQL can produce a "slowlog" that identifies "slow" queries.

Answer (score 32):

Oracle's very own Tom Kyte has a fantastic repository on every type of performance problem imaginable on http://asktom.oracle.com.  He usually takes the time to recreate specific problems and gives very detailed explanations.

Answer (score 19):

This guy's answer to a not-the-same-inquiry is probably a good start.

[Hidden Features of MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368858/hidden-features-of-mysql/600830#600830)

Answer (score 14):

And something for PostgreSQL: ["Performance Optimization"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) at the official [wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/).

Answer (score 7):

If you are using an Oracle database, this guide may also help.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/toc.htm

Answer (score 6):

For MySQL, the performance tuning 'bible' is [High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718/)

Answer (score 5):

[Quick PostgreSQL Optimization](http://www.mohawksoft.org/?q=node/56) (query optimizing)

Short read, explains a lot of things well and 'works' a real example which is nice for those of us that learn better that way.

After seeing the wiki link to PostgreSQL, figured I'd edit this post with links for [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)/[oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/index.html) docs, not really an optimization guides specifically but both are good resources, especially the mysql one. For optimization and any other tuning features.

Answer (score 3):

SO has a good one here: [How do you interpret a query’s explain plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79266/how-do-you-interpret-a-querys-explain-plan)

Answer (score 3):

A lot of good MySQL specific tips can be found at http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/

Answer (score 3):

I would add that besides having your database theoretically tuned, you should profile your application using a profiler that tracks SQL calls.

Despite your best intentions, a few bad calls will sneak into your application and will often cause 90% of your performance-related problems.

Answer (score 3):

- Book: Troubleshooting Oracle Performance (Antognini Christian)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for SQL Server specific Performance tuning references there are an absolute shed load of quality resources available online, ranging from white papers on implementing specific technologies such as partitioning, to excellent Blogs that detail step by step instruction on how to performance tune a sql server platform.

Shameless plug follows: You can start you research by reviewing the performance tuning area of my personal Blog, or for any specific SQL Server requirements/issues feel free to fire me an email.

[SQL Server Resources](http://www.johnsansom.com)

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server Performance](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/index.aspx)
Decent site for MSSQL specific info.

Answer (score 2):

### http://explain.depesz.com/

- helps you interpret **PostgreSQL**'s [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain) output.

The whole [Performance Tips](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/performance-tips.html) chapter in the PostgreSQL docs is worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

[How to Identify Slow Running Queries with SQL Profiler](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/) is a good tutorial on how to go about identifying slow running queries.  This will allow one to focus their attention where it is most needed.

Answer (score 1):

"SQL Performance Tuning" http://books.google.com/books?id=3H9CC54qYeEC&dq=sql+performance+tuning&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=1dDoSYmjMOrlnQfX-bSYBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4 covers most of the major DBMS -- how to write high performing cross platform SQL queries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Xaprb](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/) is a must-read blog for MySQL DBAs. The author has written a book on [high-performance MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716)

For the happy few working with Sybase SQL Anywhere I can only recommend [Breck Carter's blog](http://sqlanywhere.blogspot.com/) and his [SQL Anywhere Studio 9 Developer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556225067)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/jdbc.shtml
http://www.google.com/search?q=database+performance+tuning

Answer (score 1):

Here is another highly-regarded book that is platform-neutral:

Dan Tow's [SQL Tuning: Generating Optimal Execution Plans](http://books.google.com/books?id=pKXF7UU0gBYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=sql%2Btuning)

Contains some specific examples for Oracle, MS SQL, and IBM DB2, but the techniques involved should apply to other platforms, too.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, I primarily use:

- [Brent Ozar's Perf Tuning Page](http://www.brentozar.com/sql-server-performance-tuning/)
- [SqlServerPedia's Perf Tuning Page](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Performance_Tuning)

Answer (score 1):

I was pretty happy when I saw this way of quickly seeing what happened with a SQL statement you are tuning under Oracle.  Change the first SQL statement below to your SELECT statement and keep that hint in there.

```
SELECT /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */ * FROM DUAL;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display_cursor( NULL, NULL, 'RUNSTATS_LAST'))
;

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------
SQL_ID  5z36y0tq909a8, child number 0
-------------------------------------
SELECT /*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */ * FROM DUAL

Plan hash value: 272002086

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.02 |       3 |      2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


12 rows selected.
```

Where:

- E-Rows is estimated rows.
- A-Rows is actual rows.
- A-Time is actual time.
- Buffers is actual buffers.

Where the estimated plan varies from the actual execution by orders of magnitude, you know you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

For people working with Oracle I recommend this link.............

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm

From my experiences with Oracle database development, I have found that building up a knowledge of how to use SQL, how it works and knowing what is available (supplied functions, clauses that you didn't know existed or enhanced from the last version)  means I spend a lot less time having to tune sql.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start out by understanding how the database works at a fundamental level.  How is data stored on disk, what does creating an index do, how does query plan optimization work, how are plans cached, when to cached plans expire.

If you can commit all that to memory, most of the advice about tuning seems obvious.

Here's a great book for MSSQL

[SQL Server Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626243)

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, [Cost-Based Oracle: Fundamentals](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/cbo_book/ind_book.html) by [Jonathan Lewis](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to know to how to fix the problem once it is identified. This will show ways to replace a badly performing cursor with a set-based operation:
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

It was specific to SQL Server but many of the techniques might transalte to other dbs as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft SQL, I'd recommend the books by Kalen Delaney (et al) called "Inside SQL Server". They offer a good insight into the internals of SQL Server, thus allowing readers to educate themselves on why particular statements might be faster than others.

[Inside SQL Server 7.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735605173) 
[Inside SQL Server 2000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735609985) 
[Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621969) 
[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626243)

There's also a book dedicated to performance tuning of SQL Server 2008 queries:
[SQL Server Performance Tuning Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219025)

I also like the blogs by Paul Randal and Kimberly Tripp on SQLSkills.com. They are full of solid SQL advice:

[Paul's blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/) 
[Kimberly's blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/)

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server performance tuning, Itzik Ben-Gan is a legend.

You can find his many detailed books here, all with his usual style of empirical measurement to prove his case: http://tsql.solidq.com/books/index.htm

If you're searching for the fastest solution to a t-sql problem add the word 'itzik' to your google search term.

Itzik Ben-Gan has been mentioned [over 600 times here on stackoverflow](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3astackoverflow.com+itzik+ben-gan), but I couldn't believe it to find not a single mention of him here on this performance tuning question.

As an additional resource, you can also find some videos of [Itzik talking about performance related stuff here on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=itzik%20ben-gan&oq=itzik%20ben-gan&gs_l=youtube.3...0.0.0.8225.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac..11.youtube.).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle sites

1. 2 day performance tuning guide http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/toc.htm
2. Performance Tuning Guide http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36909_01/server.1111/e16638/toc.htm

Oracle books

1. Oracle Core: Essential Internals for DBAs and Developers by Jonathan Lewis
2. Expert Oracle Database Architecture: Oracle Database 9i, 10g, and 11g Programming Techniques and Solutions by Thomas Kyte
3. SQL Tuning by Dan Tow
4. Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Performance Tuning Tips & Techniques (Oracle Press) by Richard Niemiec