# Oracle DB performance

Tags: oracle, database-performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What resources exist for Database performance-tuning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761204/what-resources-exist-for-database-performance-tuning)

Can someone please suggest diagnostics steps for what caused oracle slow performance?

My application uses Oracle DB and it is cool most of the time, I sometime receive emails saying that application is extremely slow but by the time I login and check everything would be good.

I am wondering is there a way to check history (say some log file ) behind this performance issues.

If something is happening currently then I am aware to check locks (V$locks) etc.. But If I have to check what happened yesterday between 2 to 3:00PM while troubleshooting performance what should I look at?

Comment: You should look back at your old questions and see if you can't accept a few answers. 8 asked with no accepted answers isn't looking too hot.

Comment: If you have the required licensing, take a look at AWR http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3772751/Intro-to-Oracles-Automatic-Workload-Repository-AWR.htm http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/autostat.htm#i27008 http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/automatic-workload-repository-10g.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have the licenses you can browse ASH quite easily. If you don't have the licenses, or are not running Oracle Enterprise Edition of an Oracle version before 10g, you could use ASH viewer to collect and view the data offline.
Just wrote a little blog post about it.[ash for standard edition - or - without extra licenses](http://ronr.blogspot.nl/2012/10/ash-for-standard-edition-or-without.html) 
This works very easy. One challenge is to have it running during the period where a problem occurs. Studying the results can be done later.