# How to describe performance issue in relational database?

Tags: oracle, performance, relational-database, query-optimization

I have a query running in a *relational database* that doesn't fulfill the expectation of the users.

What information should I provide and what should I avoid, so that I can receive an effective help on this site?

Comment: The motivation to post this question was, that I din't found for the relational databased a page similar to 
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) one for `[r]`.
I answered this question myself for the Oracle database, with the hope is that others extend / correct the information and add answers for other databases.

Comment: This is not a blog. Would be a good start to decide what is the users expectation. (throughput, responsiveness for example)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For **Oracle Database** provide this information:

**Describe the symptoms of the problem**

Describe the behavior that cause the problem. Is the behavior of the query stable or does the problem occurs only
sometimes, with specific parameters or simple random. Can you reproduce this behavior in an IDE (e.g. SQL Developer)?

**Describe the environment**

Define the exact version of Oracle

```
 select * from v$version
```

Describe how you connect to the database: driver, ORM, programming language. Provide names and/or version numbers.

**Describe the query**

Post the query text. Try to simplify - show a **minimal reproducible example**.

Example - you problematic query joins 10 tables. Check if you see the same symptoms in a query with 9 or 8 joins.
Step down until you see the problems and show only the reduced query.

**Yes, this is costly, but it highly increase the chance that you receives support!** The smaller the query is the higher it attracts 
the supporters.

**Describe the execution plan**

To get the execution plan run this statement (substitute your query text)

```
 EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = '<some_id>' into   plan_table  FOR
     select * from ....   -- your query here 
 ;
```

The execution plan is stored in the `PLAN_TABLE`, to see it run this query

```
 SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', '<some_id>','ALL'));
```

Show the **complete result** (not only the table with the execution plan).
Extreme important may be the predicate section and the notes bellow.

Example for `select * from dual where dummy = :1;`

```
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$1 / DUAL@SEL$1

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("DUMMY"=:1)

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - "DUMMY"[VARCHAR2,1]
```

**Do not cut and paste the graphical result** of your IDE explain plan.

**Is this execution plan the real one that is executed?**

Unfortunately not always. There are several reasons the *explained* execution plan may [differ from the real one](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.at/2007/04/when-explanation-doesn-sound-quite.html).

If you are in doubts (especially when you see a good plan, but the query runs bad) you may 
extract the plan from the DB cache providing a `SQL_ID`.

```
 SELECT t.* FROM  table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR('<SQL_ID>',null,'ALL')) t;
```

The SQL_ID for a query that is currently running (or was running shortly and is still cached) can be found with
 text match and/or the database user:

```
select sql_id, sql_fulltext from v$sql a where 
 lower(sql_text) like lower('%<some identifying part of the query text>%') 
  and parsing_schema_name = '<user running the query>';
```

If you have AWR license, you may get the execution plan from there, even for queries running in history.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM  table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_AWR('10u2rj016s96k'  )) t;
```

The SQL_ID can be found using

```
select sql_id, sql_text 
from dba_hist_sqltext a 
where lower(sql_text) like lower('%<some identifying part of the query text>%')
```

**Describe the data**

Show the DDL of the tables and indexes on those tables.

Mention if the optimizer statistics are gathered recently and show the used `dbms_stats` gather statement.

For the critical table(s) provide information about segment size, row number, partitioning,...

For the columns used in access or joins provide information about number of distinct values.
Are the values evenly distributed or skew (e.g. a small number of values that occurs very often and a large number
of rare values). 
Do you define histograms?

**Anything Else?**

Of course this is the basics only and other information may still be required, such as system statistics or optimizer parameters. 
But once again try to provide the minimal information that (you thing) can identify the problem.
Post additional information upon request.

Good luck!

Comment: `Do you define histograms` correct me if i am wrong by histograms are created when the gather statistics are performed ( if mehtod_opt is default). so actually you do not define histograms as they created by default however you can remove them .

Comment: @APC your are welcome; still waiting for a post for MySQL or Postgress. That the question will be more on-topic;)

Comment: Get a SQL Monitor report. It's *the* tool to use when diagnosing a SQL performance problem. It has *way* more information that a simple explain plan

Comment: @APC there are many questions here that involved partitioning, which is also a cost option requiring EE. So I would not assert that everyone is in that boat... :)

Comment: FYI - SQL Monitor reports are only available to organisations using Enterprise Edition which have also licensed the Diagnostics and Tuning option.